# How can I make my localhost server available from external requests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost, portforwarding

I'm running a simple nodejs server on my localhost on port :3434

```
const cors = require('cors');
const app = require('express')();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.json())
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(cors());

    app.get('/ping/:anystring', (req, res) => {
            console.log(req.params['anystring']);
            res.send({
                anystring: req.params['anystring']
            })
        });

    app.listen(3434);
```

and I'd like to perform some ajax call from a website of mine.
I tried to configure the router port forwarding like so:

```
- name service: mylocalserver   
- porta ragnge: 3434    
- local ip: 192.168.1.19
- local port: 3434
- protocol: BOTH
```

but when I do

```
fetch(publicIP:3434/ping/hello).then(res => {
  console.log(res);
})
```

I get **error 404**

Might anyone help me telling what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sites on the Internet can't access sites on a local network. They are two different networks. 192.168.1.xx is a common IP address on a LAN. Telling an Internet site to go to that address doesn't work because how it the site know if it's *your* 192.168.1.xx or *my* 192.168.1.xx?

Comment: You probably will need to check with your internet provider if you do have a static ip. and get one if you want to host an app on your localserver.

Comment: Your router does not forward the request to your server, because it doesn't know that it should. You need to set up [port forwarding](https://www.whatismyip.com/port-forwarding/) on your router. The specific way to do it will depend on your router. Hopefully you will find the resource helpful

Comment: @nagyben exactly, I'm trying to set it up in order the router to forward requests on that port of my local IP, but it seems not working

Comment: Are you using the correct public IP address? http://icanhazip.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can't access your localhost server outside of your LAN unless you create a tunnel.  I use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

There is an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrok) for ngrok, but I couldn't get that one working, so I just manually start the server from terminal whenever I need to test an API.

Also you'll need [http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http).

add this to your app.js:

```
const http = require('http');

const newPort = //your port here (needs to be a different port than the port your app is currently using)

const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

  console.log(req); //code to handle requests to newPort
  res.end('Hello World);
});

app.listen(newPort, function() {
    console.log(`ngrok listening on ${newPort}`);
});
```

Now in terminal, after installing [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), use this `ngrok http newPort` where newPort = your port

You can view requests sent to your server by going to `localhost:4040` (this might change depending on your system)

To send a request to your localhost, do this:

```
- name service: mylocalserver //not sure
- porta ragnge: ???
- local ip: //ngrok gives you a url in terminal when you start the server (I'm not sure if you can reference an IP)
- local port: newPort
- protocol: http //(ngrok gives you a different url for http and https)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [local tunnel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/localtunnel) 
It maps your port on the localhost to a web url whithout the need to change your code